# Сохранение изображений

Tags: c#, wpf

Дано: набор изображений размещенных на Canvas. DecodePixel изменены что бы было меньше затрат. Класс в котором хранятся ссылки на файлы из которых было загружены, и текущие размеры/пропорции и координаты.
Вопрос: комрады, как эти изображения "слить" в одно согласно их позиции и пропорциям, в максимальном возможном качестве и самое главное сохранить итог в jpg?

PS
В процессе пошел по следующему пути, создал DrawingImage, в который через DrawingGroup закинул изображения. А дальше, ступор... как его сохранить в jpg.

Апдейт:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            Point location = new Point(temp[i].Propx* width * ver/ 25.4, temp[i].Propy*height* hor/ 25.4);
            Size size = new Size(temp[i].Propwidth*width * ver/ 25.4, temp[i].Propheight*hor* height/ 25.4);
            Rect rect = new Rect(location, size);
            drawingContext.DrawImage(tempBS[i], rect);
        }
        drawingContext.Close();

        Size finalSize = new Size(300*width/25.4, 300*height/25.4);
        var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                         (int) finalSize.Width,(int) finalSize.Height,
                          300, 300, // разрешение
                          PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
```

Где, Propx,Propy,Propwidth это пропорция размеров изображения относительно итогового. width и height - это итоговые размеры изображения в мм.ver = 300;
hor = 300;

Comment: "в максимальном возможном качестве ... в jpg" о_О

Comment: В максимальном из доступного разумеется

Comment: В jpg максимальное качество доступно, но занимает неоправданно много места.

Comment: Согласен, но такого условие, итоговое изображение должно быть jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, можно по-всякому. Например, через `RenderTargetBitmap`:

```
BitmapSource CombineImages()
{
    DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
    DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
    foreach (var image in Images)
    {
        Point location = <место вашей картинки на общей картинке>;
        Size size = <размер вашей картинки>;
        Rect rect = new Rect(location, size);
        drawingContext.DrawImage(image, rect);
    }
    drawingContext.Close();

    Size finalSize = <размер итоговой картинки>;
    var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                      finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height,
                      96, 96, // разрешение
                      PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(drawingVisual);
    return bmp;
}

void Save(BitmapSource bmp, string path)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = 100 }; // качество 1..100
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

На этом пути вам, кажется, не нужно заботиться о случае, когда картинки имеют различное разрешение и различный формат.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30091/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd--).